# Wordpress container changing concurrent maximum clients

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker

I need to change the number of clients that can connect concurrently to a wordpress Docker instance. As far as I know this is done through the MaxClients directive but I don't know in which file should I change it. Also I wonder if there is any environment variable that can be set when launching the Docker instance to change this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MaxRequestWorkers was called MaxClients before version 2.3.13

The field MaxRequestsWorkers can be configured inside the container under `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf`